# Sections with number ranges

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I've been working on an assignment, and two of the questions are very similar and it's easier to write about them both in the same section. The problem with this is it screws the numbering up:

```
1 Section Title
(Question 1)
2 Section Title
(Question 2 and 3) 
3 Section Title
(Question 4)
```

My current approach is:

```
1 Section Title
(Question 1)
2 Section Title
(Question 2 and 3) 
\setcounter{section}{3}
4 Section Title
(Question 4)
```

Ideally, what I'd like to do is:

```
1 Section Title
(Question 1)
2-3 Section Title
(Question 2 and 3) 
4 Section Title
(Question 4)
```

Is this possible? I understand that the `section` counters are based on integers, but is there a way to override their visual representation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The visual representation of the `section` counter is specified by macro `\thesection`, which can be redefined:

```
\section{Section Title}
(Question 1)

\let\savedthesection\thesection
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \arabic{section}--\the\numexpr\value{section}+1\relax
}
\section{Section Title}
\stepcounter{section}
\let\thesection\savedthesection
(Question 2 and 3)

\section{Section Title}
(Question 4)
```

Full example including patch for the table of contents to increase the spacing for the sections.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Patch section entries in table of contents to get
% more space for the section numbers
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\l@section{1.5em}{2.5em}{}{%
  \errmessage{\noexpand\l@section could not be patched}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{First question}

\let\savedthesection\thesection
\renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
  \arabic{section}--\the\numexpr\value{section}+1\relax
}
\section{Second and third question}
\stepcounter{section}
\let\thesection\savedthesection

\section{Fourth question}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

### Macro `\rangesection`

The following example defines `\rangesection` with the following arguments:

```
\rangesection{<number of additional sections>}[<toc entry>]{<section title>}
```

Also different number schemes are supported.

```
\documentclass{article}

% Patch section entries in table of contents to get
% more space for the section numbers
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\l@section{1.5em}{2.5em}{}{%
  \errmessage{\noexpand\l@section could not be patched}%
}

\newcommand*{\rangesection}[1]{%
  \@dblarg{\@rangesection{#1}}%
}
\def\@rangesection#1[#2]#3{%
  \let\saved@thesection\thesection
  \stepcounter{section}%
  \protected@edef\from@thesection{\thesection}%
  \addtocounter{section}{#1}%
  \protected@edef\to@thesection{\thesection}%
  \addtocounter{section}{-1}%
  \renewcommand*{\thesection}{%
    \from@thesection--\to@thesection
  }%
  \section[{#2}]{#3}%
  \let\thesection\saved@thesection
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\noindent\dotfill

\section{First question}

\rangesection{1}{Second and third question}

\section{Fourth question}

\renewcommand*{\thesection}{\Alph{section}}
\setcounter{section}{0}

\section{First appendix question}

\rangesection{4}{Second to sixth appendix question}

\section{Seventh appendix question}

\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: Thanks @Heiko. You've mis-spelled \savedthesection in the second instance of the first example. I can't do single character edits to change it for you. Otherwise this worked perfectly!

Comment: @Darkstarone Thanks. I had fixed it in my test file, but forgotten to update the answer.

Comment: Also the `\renewcommand` line seems to be cut of in the full example.

Comment: yw! Maybe it would be nice to add an additional version where the whole process juggling with `\thesection` is wrapped into a command named `\rangedsection` or similar. +1 anyways ;)

Comment: @Ruben Done. Also I have added support for different section number formats.